# changing the order of condition in while loop crashes the program

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, object-oriented-analysis

changing the order of condition in while loop crashes the program. If I write like: `while(a[in-1]>=temp && in>0)`, the program wont work. Why? The error is:ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1. The code below works until i make the above change.

```
 public class ISort {
public int[] sort(int[] a){
    int n=a.length;
    for(int out=1;out<n;out++){
        int temp=a[out];
        int in=out;
        while(in>0 && a[in-1]>=temp ){
           a[in]=a[in-1];
           in--;
        }
        a[in]=temp;
    }
    return a;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a={3,2,1,6,3,8,8,10,9};
    ISort s=new ISort();
    int[] res=s.sort(a);
    for(int i=0;i<res.length;i++ ){
        System.out.print(" "+res[i]+" ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the error message you get.

Comment: First rule of programming: read the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if `in` becomes `0` then `in - 1` will be `-1` and which is invalid index for array.

`while(in>0 && a[in-1]>=temp)` works because

When  `in > 0` is evaluated to `false` then due to ***short circuit*** `a[in - 1] >=temp` is not evaluated

`while(a[in-1]>=temp && in>0)` doesnt because

first `a[in - 1]` will be evaluated and when `in` reaches to `0` then `in - 1` will be `-1` and that will throw exception as `-1` is not a valid index for an array and will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 5):

Because of [*Short-circuit evaluation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If you write `while(in>0 && a[in-1]>=temp)`, then if `in <= 0`, you don't evaluate the second part.

Why?

Because the result of **false && anything** is always *false*, so it's redundant to check the other side if the first side is already evaluated to *false*.

I think you got `AarrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you changed the order because `in` was `<= 0` and you still tried to access `a` in a negative index. That's why when you want to access a method via some *object* and you're not sure whether the object is *null*, you sometimes do:

`if(myVar != null && myVar.myMethod())`

Answer (score 0):

Reason of not work of condition is that `while(a[in-1]>=temp && i>0)` array  got negative index at `in=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where `in = 0`. The first thing the will be evaluated is `a[in - 1] = a[-1] = IndexOutOfBounds`. By checking the value of `in` first, you abort checking the array index if `in` is not greater than 0.